# Basketball and rebound

Tags: rules, basketball, terminology

In basketball, why is a rebound simply not just called a bounce, ball bounce, or re-bounce? What exactly is a rebound? Also, why is a date with someone used to forget another date simply also called a rebound? What is the connection?

Comment: There ate at least two different questions here, and at least one of them is blatantly off-topic for Sports SE.

Comment: This may be better suited for English SE, as we're getting into word etymology rather than anything directly sports specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bounce refers to dribbling a basketball.  Re-bounce would mean to dribble again but it is not English so it would have no meaning.

Rebound is actually a word used when a ball or anything hits a hard object and deflects somewhere else.  This isn't just a basketball term.

The connection with the date, is using a sports analogy.  It is a rebound date because you missed on your other date/relationship but got another date quickly, just like if you missed your shot and got a rebound.